# Setting a path with whitespace in Cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin, whitespace

I set 2 environment variables to test which one works for me, as following

.bash_profile

```
NODE_BIN1="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs"
NODE_BIN2=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/nodejs
export NODE_BIN1 NODE_BIN2
```

then test them in Cygwin terminal

```
$ cd $NODE_BIN1
kevin@kevin-HP /cygdrive/c/Program  (wrong!)

$ cd $NODE_BIN2
kevin@kevin-HP /cygdrive/c/Program  (wrong!)

$ cd C:/Program Files/nodejs
kevin@kevin-HP /cygdrive/c/Program  (wrong!)

$ cd "C:/Program Files/nodejs"
kevin@kevin-HP /cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs
```

The last result is what I want but actually it's same string as $NODE_BIN1.

Any idea to fix this ? 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: probably not what you are looking for, but cd "$NODE_BIN1" works.

Comment: If it works, $NODE_BIN1/node won't show any error, but it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using cygpath?

```
export NODE_BIN1=`cygpath -w -s "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs"`
```

This also provides the same output

```
export NODE_BIN1=`cygpath -d "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs"`
```

Comment: hi, I've tested it successfully. So I can use node.exe  everywhere in console mode now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches will set the environment variable correctly.  The problem you're experiencing is when you try to use it; bash will split variables on spaces by default, and you end up calling `cd` with two arguments: `/cygdrive/c/Program` and `Files/nodejs`.

The solution, of course, is to switch to zsh.  ;)

Okay, okay.  If your intention is to be able to switch to this directory with ease, consider writing an alias instead.

```
alias cdnode='cd "/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/nodejs"'
```

If you only want to set this for node's benefit, then don't worry; you're already good to go.  You can be absolutely sure using `echo` instead.

```
$ echo "[$NODE_BIN1]"
[/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/nodejs]
```